# How to translate a zend application

Tags: zend-framework

What's the best way to translate the database content of       a zend application ?

I am thinking to add field to database tables
Or create others tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is to have two tables and a view.

Let's say we have "nouns". So, I create a table NOUN_R with only "IdLanguage" (and whatever needed), another table NOUN_TR (translation), with, "IdLanguage" , a Locale (EN, DE, ...), description and text.
So far:

### NOUN_R

---

NOUN | IDlanguage

Yellow | 1

Red     | 2

---

### NOUN_TR

NOUN | IDlanguage | Language

Yellow | 1 | EN

Giallo     | 1 | IT

Red | 2 | EN

Rosso | 2 | IT

Finally, you get a view which filters on Locale!

That's the way I'm using right now, not the "best solution" :)

Comment: Hi, Gounemond suggestion is a good starting point. I would suggest to create "labels" and "labels_resources" tables with same fields as explained but also with "module" field in labels_resources table so you will be able to translate string per module. Then generate CSV files (per module) with all translations in order to improve performance.